# Current Frame of Animation - SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

In my game I have a SpriteNode running an endless animation; the user can stop the animation by hitting a button (resume as well); I need to know the current frame of the animation, so I can read the proper value associated with it (from an XML file).

Here is my code:

```
SKAction *animateCircle = [SKAction
                         animateWithTextures:_animationTextures
                         timePerFrame: [self getAnimationSpeedAccordingToStage]];
    SKAction *repeatAnimation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animateCircle];
    [shapeNode runAction:repeatAnimation withKey:@"shapeAnimation"];
    animationStartTime = [NSDate date];
    [self resumeShapeAnimation];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SKTexture get image name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698512/sktexture-get-image-name)

Answer (score 0):

Are your animation textures numbered?
If they follow a pattern like textureNameNumber you can use this solution that I myself used:

```
  -(int) getAnimationFrameFromTexture: (SKTexture*) texture imageName:(NSString*) name
{
    NSString* textureString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", texture];
    int i;
    char numberStr[4]="000";
    for( i=0 ;i<[textureString length]; i++) 
    {
        char character = [textureString characterAtIndex:i];
        if(character=='\'')
            break; //found '
    }
   //Adds length
    i+=[name length]+1;
    for(int j=0;i<[textureString length];i++, j++)
    {
        char character = [textureString characterAtIndex:i];
        numberStr[j]=character;
        if(character=='\'')
            break;
    }
    numberFromString=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:numberStr];
    int number = [numberFromString intValue];   
    return number;
}
```